# Trying to get setText method to actually change my text in android

Tags: java, android, text

I have looked through many topics on this already and cannot for the life of me figure out what is wrong with this code. I have taken it directly out of the "Learning Android Applications programming" source code found on github

https://github.com/androiddevbook/onyourbike

**The code will not change the text from "Hello world" to "On your bike!"**

Everywhere i looked it seemed to be written correctly. I am pretty new to android development so I'm sure that is probably the case. Here is the code

**EDITED CODE SO FAR:**
MainActivity.java:

```
package com.androiddevbook.onyourbike_chapter3;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
static String className;



@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
className = getClass().getName();
TextView text1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.hello);
Log.d(className, "Setting text.");
text1.setText("On your bike!");
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
Log.d(className, "Showing menu.");
getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
return true;
}
}
```

activity_main.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<TextView
android:id="@+id/hello"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
android:layout_centerVertical="true"
 />


</RelativeLayout>
```

So apparently the issue is with the graphical layout editor. After running the code on a different android device everything worked perfectly. But it did not show up correctly in the editor. Thanks for the help everyone.

Comment: constructor for a Activity class? remove it.

Comment: haha i just revised the post. Totally forgot to mention the main issue  while trying to format the code correctly. So sorry!

Comment: look my edited answer

Comment: @user3543906 i can say that there is no need for a constructor in a Activity class. comment the log statements. And run again. It should work. And i don't know who downvoted my answer but i can say the constructor is definitely no needed.

Comment: @Tarlune you can also look at the source. http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.4.2_r1/android/app/Activity.java/. There is no constructor. But i don't see anything wrong other than that.

Answer (score -1):

Your code must be like next

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
static String className;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    className = getClass().getName();
    TextView text1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.hello);
    Log.d(className, "Setting text.");
    text1.setText("On your bike!");
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    Log.d(className, "Showing menu.");
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return true;
}
}
```

and your xml file

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/hello"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
     />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: So i went ahead and tried your suggestions. Now the emulator is showing zero text when i run it.

Comment: I'm not downvoting anyone :(

Comment: Tried adding the new line of code. Still no text. Everywhere i looked the code seemed to be written correctly. Could it be some other issue?

Comment: So I tried the new code. Still no text in emulator. So frustrating! Gah i really appreciate you trying to help by the way.

Comment: do you have only one file in your layout folder?

Comment: Yes only 1 file "activity_main.xml"

Comment: If all are correct.Try rebuilding your project.And run the application.May be sometime the IDE will make some problems.So it is the only way.You can also restart the IDE by File>Restart in Eclipse.

Comment: and if you use eclipse - make clean your project

Comment: Okay so I cleaned, restarted, and then cleaned again. Opened it up. Looking at the Graphic Layout in Eclipse it shows no text. Running the emulator shows "Hello World." Which is very odd as i have no text in my program containing the string "Hello World."

Comment: add android:text="On my byke" to your TextView in xml

Comment: if something from it helped you - please check my answer

Comment: Doesn't adding android:text="On my byke" just hard code the text into the textView? I'f i'm trying to use the setText method that's not really addressing the issue is it? Or am i mistaken?